# What facebook API do I use to remotely publish things to user's walls from my FB App?

Tags: facebook-apps

I have a FB App that a user will subscribe to via some client (Android or Web), but that later needs to post stuff to their wall (not from the client but from the server).  Assuming I have the FB-AppID, and Key and the user's UserId, and they have opted into the app, what is the API I would use to then post stuff to their wall via WGET from my server? I'm confused by all their various methodologies, and am hoping to get pointed towards the one that's the most HTTP friendly.

Comment: You might have more/faster/better luck on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: wow... had no idea there was a whole separate fb stack! wild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the "posts/Create" section under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/.

You will need publish_stream permission to push the same to facebook.

Also, you will need a valid access_token from FB which is linked to the user who has logged into your app. A standard access_token will work only for a fixed amount of time since it was last provided to you (typically 30 minutes).

If you wish to post after the said time (basically anytime), then you will need the offline_access permission also.

In essence, if you need to do a post offline, then you need to necessarily have an access token with both "offline_access" and "publish_stream" permissions.

Comment: I see... so, if I have them agree to the offline_access grant, then I should pull and hold on to that token from the response that comes back at the time of their log-in?  Or do I have to get a new token somewhere, each time I attempt to post to their wall at later dates?

Comment: You can hold on to that token forever. The token is valid till the one of the following happens: 1) User changes his password. 2) User revokes permission to your app from his app settings. 3) Facebook suspends your app for whatever reason.

Comment: Just to complete the context. If the user changes his/her FB password, then on next interaction with your app, you will get a new access token (different from the previous one) which will be equally good. However, if the user doesn't return to your app or interacts with it, then you don't have a valid access token for that duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook Graph API. This api is HTTP based and support REST services.

Here is the link -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
You must be login in Facebook to access this page.