# i'm trying to send message to my facebook friend in my own website. how can i do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some problem to send message to facebook using my own website.

on my website i load some facebook element using ajax request like below :

```
$('#loader').load('https://m.facebook.com/messages/compose/ids?=xxxxxxxxxxxx form#composer_form',function(){
       // some code 
});
```

and the result is i get the form to send message to facebook BUT the problem is when i submit the form, it redirect me to the "Content not found" page.

is there any solution with this?

Comment: Not sure, for security reasons, that Facebook allows remote posting.

Comment: but i'm able to use this method to login into my facebook account.

Comment: I think you need to use a proper Facebook API, and not just "steal" a form from them :) Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597707/what-facebook-api-do-i-use-to-remotely-publish-things-to-users-walls-from-my-fb

Comment: i know facebook API can do this but it has so many limitation.... using my method above i can get all what i want from my facebook account but the problem is when i want to do POST Request to facebook like sending message.... it shows me "CONTENT NOT FOUND" page.... :(

Comment: What is the URL it posts to? I'm not sure you can bypass Facebook security and API limitations so easily. Worth a try, though.

Comment: it seems i gotta work harder for this..... thanks for your response :)